# My How can I assign an empty object to an object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have code like this:

The interface:

```
interface IAuthService {

    forms: {
        chn: any;
        che: any;
        cpw: any;
        fpw: any;
        login: any;
        logout: any;
        r: any;
        rpw: any;
    };
```

My class:

```
class AuthService implements IAuthService {

    forms: {
        chn: any;
        che: any;
    };

static $inject = [
    '$interval'
];

constructor(
    public $interval
    ) {

    this.forms = {
        chn: {},
        che: {}
    };

}
```

Can someone tell me if I can do the assignement:

```
  chn: {},
  che: {}
```

in the first few lines of the code and what if any reason would there be to do it in the constructor? Also if it is possible to do inside of the

```
  forms: {
        chn: any;
        che: any;
```

then how can I do this? I tried some different combinations but all give me syntax errors.

```
  forms: {
        chn: any = {};
```

gives me the errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  TS2420  Class
>   'AuthService' incorrectly implements interface 'IAuthService'.   Types
>   of property 'forms' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ chn: any; }' is not assignable to type '{ chn: any; che: any;}'.
>         Property 'che' is missing in type '{ chn: any; }'.  user    C:\H\user\user\app\services\authservice.ts  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark some fields (properties) as optional with "?":

```
interface IAuthService {

forms: {
    chn: any;
    che: any;
    cpw?: any;
    fpw?: any;
    login?: any;
    logout?: any;
    r?: any;
    rpw?: any;
};
```

in this case you can make such an assignment:

```
this.forms = {
    chn: {},
    che: {}
};
```

and this:

```
this.forms = {
    chn: {},
    che: {},
    cpw: {}
};
```

but NOT this:

```
this.forms = {
    chn: {}
};
```